# typo3 flush cache additional action

Tags: caching, hook, typo3, flush

How can I add a task to Typo3's "Clear all caches"-action?

I have written a frontend plugin with its own XML-file based caching system and I want to give the administrators the possibility to flush this cache by using the standard buttons.

Is there a possibility to register p.e. user_extension_pi1->flushAll() to system's caching mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use hook for that.

In ext_localconf.php write:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['clearCachePostProc'][] = 'EXT:yourext/class.tx_yourext_hooks.php:tx_yourext_hooks->clearCachePostProc';
```

Then in the class.tx_yourext_hooks.php create class tx_yourext_hooks with function clearCachePostProc

```
function clearCachePostProc(&$params, &$pObj) {
```

Debug $params to see what parameters you can use inside this function.

Comment: You can habe a look at the rhtmlarea system extension.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to register separate cache clear hook

> Register following in ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['additionalBackendItems']['cacheActions']['custom_key'] =
 'NAMESPACE_OF_CLASS';
```

> The class must have implement

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Toolbar\ClearCacheActionsHookInterface
```

> And Override Its Method

```
public function manipulateCacheActions(&$cacheActions, &$optionValues) {
    //YOUR CUSTOM CODE OF OVERRIDE
}
```